# Printing out an array with jQuery on a webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I've learnt jQuery recently and want to create a small To-Do list with it. But I'm stuck here because I couldn't proceed with printing out my declared array into the HTML document.

Can't really find out the reason why, any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xbili/vwjp2/4/

I don't really understand why wouldn't this work:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= x; ++i) {
     $("main").text(toDoList[i]);
 };
```

Comment: Looks like you're *replacing* the content of the `<main>` element with each loop, rather than appending to it.

Comment: He does have a <main> tag if you look at the fiddle, my first idea was the hashtag on the main as well until I saw the main tag... first I've seen of the <main> tag.

Comment: The loop is executed when clicking a button dynamically added... but the event was registered before... so that is the problem.

Comment: Also, you do not need to SUBMIT - that implies a trip to the server. You can simply use an ONCLICK event for a regular button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code for :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navButtonTBD, .navButtonD").click(function () {
        $("main").html('<input class="inputBar" type="text" placeholder="what to do?" /> <input class="toDoIt" type="submit" value="To-Do it!" />');

    });

   $(document).on("click", ".toDoIt" , function () {
            $("main").append("<p>" + $(".inputBar").val() + "</p>");
        });

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/neEjp/)

There were several erros on your original code, for example:

```
$(".inputBar").val()=toDoList[x];
```

I guess you are trying to store value in the array but that's not how is done, you could had instead use :

```
toDoList.push($(".inputBar").val());
```

However, there is no really a need to do this as you can just keep appending to your cointainer using:

```
  $("main").append("<p>" + $(".inputBar").val()  + "</p>" );
```

Comment: That's still just really wrong, attaching an event handler inside an event handler etc.

Comment: I think I get what you mean now. But what's the reason for not nesting an event handler into another event handler?

Comment: Due to the way that browsers handle event bubbling also, it is considered a bad practice and your events should be independent one from the other, when an application grows it would be insanely difficult to maintain that type of design, you can find a good lecture in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533023(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Heres a fiddle with a working version of what your end goal is:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vwjp2/7/)

I cleaned up the css by adding cursor styles but I kept your html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toDoList = [];
    $(".navButtonTBD").click(function() {
        $("main").html('<input class="inputBar" type="text" placeholder="what to do?" /> <input class="toDoIt" type="submit" value="To-Do it!" />')
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', '.toDoIt', function() {

        toDoList.push($('.inputBar').val());
        var newhtml = "";
            for(var i=0;i<toDoList.length;i++) {
               newhtml += toDoList[i]+"<br>";
            };
            //Print out toDoList below
            $("main").html(newhtml);
        });

});
```